# Unity 3d - Trouble deserialising a Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list

So, I have a Json file that contains two class members, as shown below:

```
{
"Item": 
 [

    {
        "itemID": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "description": "fluff",
        "value": 2,
        "weight": 50,
        "quantity": 5,
        "type": "Craftable",
        "favourited": false,
        "rt": null
    },
    {
        "itemID": 2,
        "name": "Star Shard",
        "description": "fluff",
        "value": 2,
        "weight": 50,
        "quantity": 5,
        "type": "Craftable",
        "favourited": false,
        "rt": null
    }
] }
```

I try to parse it into a list/array/or a member of that class inside C# at runtime, but it fails.

Here is the code in c#:

```
[System.Serializable]
```

public class Item_Pickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string filepath;

```
public class Item
{

    public int itemID;
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public int value;
    public int weight;
    public int quantity;
    public string type;
    public bool favourited;
    public RectTransform rt;

    public static Item CreateFromJson(string jsonstring)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Item>(jsonstring);
    }
    void start() 
    {

        filepath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Json1.json");
        StreamReader Test = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string e = Test.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        Item[] items = JsonUtility.FromJson<Item[]>(e);

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
        print(item.name);
        //returns null, the list contains no data. 
        }
    } }
```

The above code returns a value of null for the array, so it seems it isn't reading the json correctly.

If I set the json up to contain one class member, not as part of an array, I can easily read the class and assign it to a class in the c# script at runtime.

Am I missing something fundamental in how to correctly read a json file with multiple class members inside of an array? I looked at Newtonsoft, but it seems that isn't supported in the current version of Unity.

Comment: I think you need to make the array the top level. So rather than `{ "Item": [....`, just put `[ {....}`. At the moment you top level is a property called `Item`.

Comment: `JsonUtility.FromJson<Item[]>(e)` , No, your top level object is a class containing `Item[]` like `public class Root{ public Item[] Item; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with RectTransform, Json doesn't support it thus not identifying when desalinizing.

Try making it vector3